# Auth0: Not authorized for query on db.collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, auth0

I'm trying to connect my Mongodb with Auth0 authorization. I'm using Mlabs to host my db. Inside this db, I have a "users" collection, and the documents have "username", "password", "email, and "_id" keys. When I try to use the Auth0 login script, I get the following error: Not authorized for query on mydb.users. Below is the script:

```
function login(email, password, callback) {
  mongo('<mongodb uri>', function (db) {
    var users = db.collection('users');
    console.log(users);
    users.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {

      if (err) return callback(err);

      if (!user) return callback(new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(email));

      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, isValid) {
        if (err) {
          callback(err);
        } else if (!isValid) {
          callback(new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(email));
        } else {
          callback(null, {
            user_id: user._id.toString(),
            nickname: user.nickname,
            email: user.email
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Any ideas why I might be getting this error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to check for a connection to the db.
The callback should have an error parameter

```
 mongo('<mongodb uri>', function (err,db) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
     }
 })
```

if that doesn't fix it then you have to assign read and write permissions to perform the intended operations (in your case read) on the specified database

Comment: Ok, I installed an Auth0 log extention, and I see this error now: ` [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' `

Comment: I'm also getting the error "user already exists" when trying to run the create user script... even when I use unique emails.

Comment: Ok, the error I see now is `Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined`